# Ошибка 400 (Bad Request) при ajax-запросе в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, ajax

Битый час потратил на реализацию простейшего ajax запроса. Выкинул все запросы к БД из кода. Уже просто пробую пример из Codex'а, и то выдаёт ошибку:

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );
function my_action_javascript() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var data = {
            'action': 'ajaxresponse',
            'whatever': 1234
        };
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
    </script> 
<?php } ?>

<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxresponse', 'ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxresponse', 'ajax_function' );
function ajax_function() {
    global $wpdb;
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
    $whatever += 10;
    echo $whatever;
    wp_die();
}
?>
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Чему равен ajaxurl?

Comment: @Krya Путь скрипт берёт верный из переменной ajaxurl: https://pogrebok.com.ua/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. Забыл сказать, что код выполняется в админке, а там ajaxurl определён глобально.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.post(ajaxurl... - эта переменная должна показывать путь к файлу wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. Здесь только название, которое никуда не ведет.
Надо передать этот параметр через хук и функцию, что то типа:

```
    add_action("init", 'get_yandex_data');
    function get_yandex_data(){
        $vars = [
            'ajax_url'  =>  admin_url('admin-ajax.php')

        ];

        echo "<script>window.wp = ".json_encode($vars). " </script>";
wp_die();
    }
```

А пото указать ее, в качестве пути:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: window.wp.ajax_url,
    data: action //ваш обработчик
```

Comment: Уже лучше. Хотя странно, сам кодекс говорит, что "С версии 2.8 javascript переменная ajaxurl определена глобально на всех страницах админки. Используйте её в js коде, как ссылку на файл обработчик AJAX запроса. Обычно это файл /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" И консоль при ошибке 400 пишет "POST https://pogrebok.com.ua/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)", т.е. путь к admin-ajax.php находит. 
Только теперь результат приходит странный: "Got this from the server: <!DOCTYPE html>....дальше..html...код... "
А должен отдать просто: "Got this from the server: 1244"

Comment: Так версия jquery подходящая? Обычно в wordpress древняя версия установлена

Comment: Версию не смотрел, WP обновлён до последней версии.

Comment: И, к стати, Ваш код таки не работает. Выдаёт "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input". Рано обрадовался.

Comment: Эта ошибка "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" говорит о том, что где-то в коде не хватает знаков, закрывающих скобок, запятых или закрывающих тегов (если не ошибаюсь)

Comment: В конце функции, которая на сервере обрабатывает ajax надо не забыть wp_die();

Comment: Пунктуация соблюдена, wp_die(); присутствует, подключил jquery-2.2.4.min.js, путь к  admin-ajax.php  прописал вручную. Просто загадка какая-то!

Comment: Отладчик что говорит?

Comment: Query Monitor? Молчит, ошибок не показывает. Отладчик браузера? Как я и сказал, если использовать переменную ajaxurl, даёт ошибку 400. Если путь к admin-ajax.php прописать вручную - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: Ошибку 400 выдает, если нет action  Вот кусок кода из  admin-ajax.php: `if ( ! has_action( "wp_ajax_{$action}" ) ) {
  wp_die( '0', 400 );
 }`

Comment: action есть. Это первое, что проверил.

Comment: Вопрос с "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" отпал. Нашёл свою ошибку, глаз замылился.

Comment: Ошибка 400 выскакивает всё равно.

Comment: Так, а где у тебя в массиве data указан action?

Comment: $.ajax ({
    url: window.wp.ajax_url,
    data: { action :  'функция обработчик" //ваш обработчик

Comment: Мне в соседней ветке (проблема тоже подобная) прямо на это и указали.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1113919/wordpress-%d0%b8-ajax/1113929?noredirect=1#comment1922929_1113929

Comment: Как где? В массиве data же. Код вверху, в главном сообщении поста: var data = {
            'action': 'ajaxresponse',
            'whatever': 1234
        };

Comment: Вот взгляни, пишет мне спец, что код работать не будет мой, если нет action

Comment: Тогда остается только путь

Comment: Правильно. Но у меня-то action задан!?

Comment: попробуй переименовать асtion в соответствии с тем, что указано в хуке, то есть ajaxresponse

Comment: Хоть ajaxurl (кстати alert (ajaxurl); выдаёт верный путь), хоть  этот путь пишу вручную, один ляд. У меня уже мозги закипают @(o_O)@

Comment: На какой странице? Дай ссылку

Comment: Это страница админки.

Comment: my_action_javascript - почему у тебя эта функция обернута в скрипт?  Эта функция должна быть в или functions.php или в одном из подключаемых к нему файлов, а тут внутри скрипт

Comment: Потому, что это и есть js-функция. Просто я её не стал выносить в отдельный js-файл. Тут дело не в этом. А вот в чём, я и не могу понять. Пробовал выносить в отдельный файл. Результат тот же.

Comment: Мое мнение, что надо попробовать написать ajax запрос в футере. Файл functions.php вызывается первым, как в нем может сработать ready? В нем нет дом элементов. А когда все сработает, тогда и можно его выносить куда душе угодно. Главное, чтобы заработало. Рефакторинг потом.

Comment: Этот скрипт и вызывается в футере: add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); Да и зачем мне DOM? Я с ним не работаю. И да, я и пытаюсь, чтобы хоть как-то заработало.

Comment: Попробуй без этого. Убери этот хук и эту функцию. Просто напиши скрипт в футере без оберток.  Зачем тебе этот хук вообще? Если ты путь пишешь напрямую, то эта функция тебе совсем ни к чему.

Comment: Если ты хочешь так оставить, то надо этот скрипт запустить с помощью echo().  Как он сам по себе сработает в php функции?

Comment: Для этого и есть хук add_action( 'admin_footer', 'js' ); Не в скрипте дело, он срабатывает (например я помещу alert(); и он сработает). Тут какая-то другая причина!!!1111бьюсь_головой_в_клавиатуру.

Comment: И ещё раз, это пример дословно из кодекса, мать его! Как он может не работать?!?!?!

Comment: я запустил у себя, как есть, все прошло, и ответ 124 получил. Просто скопировал код, вставил в рандомное место в functions.php и все сработало.

Comment: Единстенное, что я все-таки путь указал свой, через window.wp.ajax_url

Comment: И так сработало:  jQuery.post("/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(response) {
                alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
            });

Comment: Вот и я о том же, должно работать. Что-то где-то глубже зарыто.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема решилась накатом предыдущей версии WordPress 5.3 поверх текущей 5.4. Что был за глюк, до сих пор не знаю. В ядре никто не копался.