# Wordpress и ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, ajax

Есть wordpress и ajax запрос. Action в массиве data отсутствует. Какая фукнция обрабатывает запрос?

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        async: false,
                        data: $(".cart-form").serialize(),
                        success : function(data) {
                            //error_flag = true;
                            //$(".cart-form .message").html('<span>' + data + '</span>').slideDown(300);
                            // console.log(data);
                            if(data == 'OK')
```

Answer (score 0):

Никакая. Внутри admin-ajax.php есть проверка на присутствие action. Если нет - ответ 400.

Comment: Тогда каким образом данные попадают в базу? Ведь это стандартное действие serialize() с данными формы и отправкой. Как они обрабатываются?

Comment: Я не знаю, как и что у вас там попадает в базу. Тот код, что вы привели, работать не может в принципе: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/427405535fcf8f2825c1dfbfcafe68adc35906c2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#L32

Comment: Не может работать из-за отсутствия action? Но, видимо, раз есть файл admin-ajax.php, к которому обращается данный запрос, то ответ OK   приходит в ответ.

Comment: Послушайте, я вам ясно указал на код. Разберитесь, что на самом деле у вас происходит. Посмотрите запрос в dev tools. Включите отладчик и посмотрите, что происходит в admin-ajax.php